# Convert list comprehension python to javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to convert some python code into JavaScript code.

I have a python list comprehension that take the paramente `a` as input. `a` is a string such as "bac".

```
asubstring = [a[i:i + j] for j in range(1, len(a) + 1) for i in range(len(a) - j + 1)]
```

The output is: `['b', 'a', 'c', 'ba', 'ac', 'bac']`

I converted it into JavaScript by doing:

```
let j = 1
let i = 0
while(j < aTrimmed.length+1) {
    while(i < aTrimmed.length - j + 1) {
       aSubstring.push(aTrimmed.slice(i, i+j))
       i++
    }
    j++
}
```

**However**, my output is: `[ 'b', 'a', 'c' ]`

I am not sure what I am missing in the two while loops.

Comment: You didn't reset `i = 0` in the inner loop. I would suggest writing this using nested `for` loops, then it's harder to make that mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not resetting the `i` variable in the inner loop. In the Python version, `for i in range(...)` always makes `i` start from `0`. Additionally, declaring an iteration variable, then using a `while` loop which ends in incrementing that variable is a bit weird, why not just use a `for` loop?

```js
let aTrimmed = "abc";
let aSubstring = [];

for (let j = 1; j <= aTrimmed.length; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= aTrimmed.length - j; i++) {
    aSubstring.push(aTrimmed.slice(i, i + j));
  }
}

console.log(aSubstring);
```

Also note the `<=` instead of `< ... + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` loop instead of `while` because you are forgetting reset you `i` index to 0 at the end of the second loop.

```
let aTrimmed = "bac";
let aSubstring = [];


for(let j = 1; j < aTrimmed.length+1; j++) {
    for(let i = 0; i < aTrimmed.length - j + 1; i++) {
       aSubstring.push(aTrimmed.slice(i, i + j));
    }
}
alert(aSubstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

This version works more favourably with characters outside of the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane. Although there remain issues with grapheme clusters.

```js
let s1 = "abc"
let s2 = ""

function substrings(s) {
    let us = [...s]
    let result = []

    for (let j = 1; j <= us.length; j++) {
      for (let i = 0; i <= us.length - j; i++) {
        result.push(us.slice(i, i + j).join(''))
      }
    }

    return result
}

console.log(substrings(s1))
console.log(substrings(s2))
```